# Unlink chart from data series in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet

Is it possible to create a chart on a data series in Calc, and then unlink it so that if I sort that same data a different way, my chart wont change?

i am trying to show some trends based on several different factors all coming from the same data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK unlinking isn't possible, but why not copying the complete sheet? This way, you get a second/third copy of your data series without manually selecting / copying / inserting the data anywhere else.

[image: copy sheet menu]

[image: copy sheet dialogue]

Comment: Please make sure in the copying sheet you see DataRange option. If you see DataTable which is embedded with the chart, the work around will not work!!.